# Windows Essentials 2012 Server: Client connector does not work, Clients can't join

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-essentials

Several Windows 7 clients should join the Windows Essentials 2012 Server but the Connector always throws an error:

`ServerLocator.log`:

```
GetAdapterAddress with Error 0
```

`ComputerConnector.log`:

```
ccomputerconnector::ErrorDlgProc:IDD_PROPAGE_ERROR Initialization
```

Any hints where to look? At first I suspected the network but this appears to be fine. The machines can ping each other.

Google also did not helped with these errors.

Comment: See if anything in these articles help: [Troubleshoot connecting computers to the server in Windows Server Essentials](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635102.aspx) and [Windows 2012 Server Essentials Connect: Computer Troubleshooting](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14370.windows-2012-server-essentials-connectcomputer-troubleshooting.aspx)

Comment: This looks good!

Comment: Try this KB as it fixed my issue with this:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2828269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by IPv6 connection problems. After disabling IPv6 on the network and the clients it worked fine.